# Why java.util.Date is giving me wrong time?

Tags: java, date

```
System.out.println(new Date());

Thu Feb 23 04:57:57 ACT 2012
```

I am running it in a main method. And my system current time is PKT. But it's giving me ACT time.

Any idea? How to get correct system's time?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the time zone, not the `Date` value itself. So instead of printing out the current date, use something like this to print out the current time zone:

```
import java.util.TimeZone ;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        System.out.println(zone.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println(zone.getID());
    }
}
```

For example, for me that prints:

```
Greenwich Mean Time
Europe/London
```

Once you know more details about what Java thinks your default time zone is, you can start looking for *why* it thinks that. Is there anything about how you're running Java which is non-standard? Any environment variables which look suspiciously like the incorrect time zone?

You might also want to print out the following system properties, which are used when determining the time zone:

```
user.timezone
user.country
java.home
```

(Print them out *before* getting the default time zone - `user.timezone` is set as part of fetching it, if it wasn't set before.)

Comment: Strange. I run this program and it gives me Acre Time America/Rio_Branco. Where as my windows time is UTC+5. I should see why it think this.

Comment: Additionally we 2 people getting wrong time and we have 1.6.13 version. Where as a guy who has 1.6.26 getting it correct.

Comment: I am getting following values. Holy cow. My windows settings are ignored.
user.timezone = America/Rio_Branco
user.country = US
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre

Comment: @TahirAkram: Are you getting that for user.timezone *before* you call `TimeZone.getDefault`?

Comment: @ Jon: Yes I am having the same result. I run those properties before getting the default time zone.

Comment: @TahirAkram: Okay, so that sounds like something is *explicitly* setting user.timezone. What do you see on a machine where it works?

Comment: @ Jon: It works finally. I updated my system timezone to some thing else. And then I updated again to UTC+5. And it gave me same clock time that I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You may have 'forced' your TimeZone somewhere else in you code or in linked libs

```
static {
      TimeZone.setDefault(anotherTimeZone);
}
```

This will trigger this kind of behaviour, even in the main.

Comment: But how it works? Do I have to declare TimeZone once somewhere or in every class I have?

Answer (score 1):

java.util.Date gives system date. Change your system time UTC to GMT.