# Calendar returns date in wrong time zone

Tags: java, date, datetime

If I execute the following on a computer in the GMT timezone

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST');  // India Standard Time
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);

System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

It prints

> Fri Oct 31 15:18:22 GMT 2014

Why is the date printed in the computer's default time zone, rather than the `TimeZone` the `Calendar` was constructed with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Calendar returning the wrong hour with the correct time-zone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299659/why-is-calendar-returning-the-wrong-hour-with-the-correct-time-zone) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1516213/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9410806/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14124701/642706) and many more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

because `Date` object doesn't have timezone as part of its state, You need SimpleDateFormat to format and print the date in your required timezone

Answer (score 12):

The [Answer by Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26678065/642706) is correct but brief. I'll expand a bit, and show an alternative with modern classes.

## `Date` has no time zone

Your code `calendar.getTime()` extracts a `java.util.Date` object from the `java.util.Calendar` object.

The `java.util.Date` class has a well-intentioned but confusing feature where its [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) method applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the string. This creates the illusion that the `Date` class has a time zone when it does not. A `Date` represents a moment on the timeline as a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference date of first moment of 1970 UTC (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`). (Even more confusing, the `Date` class actually *does* have a time zone nestled deep inside, but is unreachable and irrelevant to this discussion.)

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Instead use only the java.time classes.

## `Instant`

For a moment in UTC, the equivalent to `java.util.Date`, use the `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // Current moment in UTC.
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

To view the same moment through the lens of a particular region’s [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

Search Stack Overflow for many other Questions and Answers on this topic. This Question is really a duplicate of many others.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

When converting the Calendar object to a Date object the timezone is lost. Calendar itself uses the timezone. The following prints to the specified timezone.

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST');  // India Standard Time
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);

System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + 
(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " Time: " + 
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
 System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

**(Note do not use the Calendar API like this, its very messy. Use the date formatting api)**

The Date api has many issues (that's why its been completely redone in java 8).

Answer (score -1):

[Calendar#getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) - Returns a Date object representing this Calendar's time value (millisecond offset from the Epoch.To be precise the value within a java.util.Date is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, which occurred at midnight January 1st 1970, UTC. and java.util.Date has no specific time zone.

Introduced in Java 8, [ZoneDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) should serve your purpose:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
LocalDate localDate = zonedDateTime.toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to apply timezone before you print the date/time

example:
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

(code not tested)