# Could not parse Date correctly for 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 EST in Java

Tags: java, date, debugging, time, simpledateformat

I am trying to pass startDate's time as **00:00:00**  and endDate's time as **23:59:59** but during debugging startDate's time is **Thu Aug 09 10:30:00 IST 2018**  and endDate's time is **Tue Aug 14 10:29:59 IST 2018**.Where am I doing wrong?

```
SimpleDateFormat estFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
estFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));

Date startDate=estFormat.parse(sdate+" 00:00:00");
object.setStartDate(startDate);

Date endDate=estFormat.parse(edate+" 23:59:59"); 
object.setEndDate(endDate);
```

provided the sdate and edate are strings which have dates in **MM/dd/yyyy** format.

**SOLUTION: USING JAVA-TIME API**

```
    sdate=sdate.trim()+" 00:00:00";
    edate=edate.trim()+" 23:59:59";
    DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime localdatetime = LocalDateTime.parse(sdate,df);
    Date startDate = Date.from(localdatetime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York" )).toInstant());
    object.setStartDate(startDate);

    localdatetime = LocalDateTime.parse(edate,df);
    Date endDate = Date.from(localdatetime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York" )).toInstant());
    object.setEndDate(endDate);
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong, you got the US Eastern Time you requested. What you're seeing is those time converted to India Time when you *print* the values. It's a formatting issue on output. The values in memory are correct. Remember, a `java.util.Date` doesn't have a time zone, and is internally stored in UTC. Time zone conversions are applied when parsing and formatting the value.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: so it means that the date passed in the code is correct? and will produce correct output?@Andreas

Comment: Ok I will try joda time and will post here if i face any error..@OleV.V.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calendar returns date in wrong time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678030/calendar-returns-date-in-wrong-time-zone)

Comment: Just to clear up in case you misread, I said java.time, not Joda-Time. Joda-Time will already be a step forward, but is in maintenance mode. java.time is related and is the more modern one of the two.

Comment: @OleV.V. sorry I misread Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.of( 2018 , Month.MAY , 23 )
.atStartOfDay(
    ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" )
)
```

## Details

Never use the terrible old legacy date-time classes such as `Date`.

Use modern *java.time* classes.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MAY , 23 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

When tracking an entire day, do not try to nail down the last moment. We commonly define a span of time using the Half-Open approach where the beginning is inclusive while the ending is exclusive. So a day starts with the first moment (typically at 00:00, but not always), and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the *next* day.

```
LocalDate dayAfter = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = dayAfter.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Tip: Add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class.

```
org.threeten.extra.Interval interval = 
    Interval.of( 
        zdtStart.toInstant() ,
        zdtStop.toInstant()
    )
;
```

The class carries handy comparison methods such as `abuts`, `contains`, `encloses`, `intersection`, and more.

```
boolean containsMoment = interval.contains( Instant.now() ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want IST timings, just change from EST to IST your line 2:

```
estFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
```