# Date and timezone conversion

Tags: java, date, timezone

How can I convert `"E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"` (String type) to Date object in Java? I have tried parsing, but it gives a string output.

```
DateFormat dfNy1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
dfNy1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));

final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

System.out.println(df.format(dfNy1.parse("Thu Dec 13 00:00:00 EST 2018")));
```

Output: `Thu Dec 13 05:00:00 UTC 2018`

Iam getting the output in String format, But I need the same as Date object.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Parsing is correct. Only don’t format because formatting will give you a string back (that’s what formatting means). `ZonedDateTime.parse("Thu Dec 13 00:00:00 EST 2018", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT))` yields a `ZonedDateTime` of `2018-12-13T00:00-05:00[America/New_York]`.

Comment: Yes: `dfNy1.parse("Thu Dec 13 00:00:00 EST 2018")`gives you the `Date` you want. Why are you formatting it?

Comment: Are you really after a `Date` with a specific time zone and format? Such a beast doesn’t exist. A `Date` is a point in time, it cannot have neither time zone nor format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion). Or of [want current date and time in “dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS” format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745297/want-current-date-and-time-in-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-ss-format) and [Calendar returns date in wrong time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26678030/calendar-returns-date-in-wrong-time-zone).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Ole and Maurice.. dfNy1.parse("Thu Dec 13 00:00:00 EST 2018") this gives me the output in date type.. but the timezone changes to that of default one..

Comment: No it doesn’t, @Shubha, sorry. I repeat, a `Date` hasn’t got and cannot have a time zone. What confuses you is that `Date.toString` grabs your JVM’s default time zone and uses it for generating the string that is printed when you print the date. This tells nothing about what is inside the `Date` object. Instead you need to use `ZonedDateTime` from java.time. As the name says, contrary to  a `Date` this *does* hold a time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Format method of SimpleDateFormatter class has return type of StringBuffer so If you want to format a date it will always return string.

You can read java docs for the same.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

When you format a date from one pattern to another date object from that string will still remain the same. So why do you want to convert your object into date?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't format date again , it will return in string format.

```
DateFormat dfNy1 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
dfNy1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));

try {
        Date d = dfNy1.parse("Thu Dec 13 00:00:00 EST 2018");
        System.out.println(s);`enter code here`
} catch (ParseException e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out, you can already successfully parse your `String` value into a `Date` object:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
Date date = df.parse("Thu Dec 13 00:00:00 EST 2018");
```

But as a `Date` object is an 'instant in time', it does not hold any time-zone information; it is nothing more than a container for milliseconds, which means after parsing **the time-zone information gets lost**. See [Java API doc for `Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> The class Date represents a specific instantin time, with millisecond precision

Fortunately, since Java 8 there is a new time-API (see [package `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)) that has many features that are missing in the old `Date` or `Calendar` API.

To parse your `String` value into a full-featured date/time object including time zone, use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` now:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.parse("Thu Dec 13 00:00:00 EST 2018", dtf);
```

Now you can use this `java.time.ZonedDateTime` directly, or convert it to any other time zone, preserving the "instant in time":

```
ZonedDateTime gmtTime = time.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("GMT");
```

If you are just interested in the local time (skipping time zone information), convert it to a `LocalDateTime`:

```
LocalDateTime localTime = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
LocalDateTime localGmtTime = gmtTime.toLocalDateTime();
```

For more information about how to use the new API, have a look at this [Tutorial about the Java time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).